# a usb flash drive shows sandrive.lnk when i mount it

Tags: windows-7, usb, encryption, mount, usb-flash-drive

i have a usb flash drive that contains multiple folders and app.exe, when i mount it, it only shows usbflashdrive.lnk(nulldll32.exe) when i double click on it, it shows me the folders inside and i can excute the app just fine.
when i copied the files inside, to my local computer(i used kali liux), and unmounted the usb flash drive, the application returns an error "a key is required to excute the app, please insert the key". i mounted the usb  again and  the app  wroked fine(no error).
i need to run the application on multiple computers at the same time, and i only have one usb flash drive.
is there a way around it ?

Answer (score 0):

If your computers are all on the same local area network (LAN), then the solution is simple,

NOTE: for all the links, right click on it and select "open in new tab", or you will lose this page.

Go to the following link: https://www.usb-over-network.com/usb-over-network.html

USB over Network
"Share and access USB devices over local network or the Internet."
"Available for Windows and Linux."

Download and install the server app on your pc, with your usb device plugged in,

Then, download and install the client application on all the other computers on your local area network.

You will not only be able to use this USB that is plugged into your computer, but also share it with any other device out there.

Please watch these two (2) videos first, to familiarize yourself with the software that will resolve your problem:

"USB over Network"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xo_7M7S9eQs

"How to Share USB Devices over a Local Network"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwHzlU5aeHE

This software has many uses, not just for USB over LAN but also over WAN (wide area network, or Internet devices NOT on a LAN).

[Share Many USB Plugin Devices over network example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFjd8.png)

I believe this will solve your problem,

All the best